# Why initializer list with dangle comma is allowed in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I was surprised that following code compiles even produces correct result.
Question is why C++11 allows dangling commas in initializer list?

```
auto l = {1,3,};
std::vector<int> v{ {1,3,}, };
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cd941373f75292a)

Comment: What sort of "why?" answer are you looking for? Rationale? Or just the dry letter of the standard?

Comment: Why not? What's the harm? It's unambiguous.

Comment: Why not? Dangling commas don't cause any harm, enums accept dangling commas too.

Comment: yes, I want to understand the reason. Since for me it is ambiguous and seems like syntax error.

Comment: Dangling commas wouldn't cause any harm only if they were consistently allowed. Right now it is a total mess. I would prefer them to be prohibited though. Reading something like `{1,3,}` makes me think that whoever wrote it forgot to write the last item.

Comment: IMO it makes it easier to rearrange items in the list (if you put one per line) or add new items using cut'n'paste, or using a macro. When columnated each entry has the same syntactic form.

Comment: Removing dangling commas when reorganizing stuff is annoying. This is fanservice for developers :)

Comment: what about `std::vector<int> v{ {1,3}, }` ? it is constructor of vector. what constructor should be called?